# How to end a bad request silently

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server, request

How can i end a bad request in nodejs. For example:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    //lets say a user sends a bad request
    checkIfRequestIsGoodorBad()
    //After finding out that the request is bad, how do i terminate it before it reaches doSomething()
    doSomething()
}).listen()
```

Comment: a `return` statement (inside an `if` block) should do it

Comment: what happens if the return statement is in a callback function?

Comment: Do you want to return a http error-response to the client or just kill the connection?

Comment: i want to send a response then kill the connection

Answer (score 1):

This should work:
(if you need callbacks then just swap the functions to async)

```
function checkIfRequestIsGoodorBad(req,res){
    if(req.url==="/naughty"){
        return "Bad"
    }else{
        return "Good"
    }
}
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    //lets say a user sends a bad request
    if(checkIfRequestIsGoodorBad(req)==="Good"){//passing req as an argument
        doSomething()
    }else{
        handleBadRequest()
    }
}).listen()
```

Answer (score 1):

- make the `checkIdRequestisGoodOrBad` return a boolean
- test `if` the boolean is true
- `if` true use the `return` keyword

```js
const checkIfRequestIsBad = (request) => {
    // your business logic
    return true // return true or false
}
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(checkIfRequestIsBad(req)) return;

    doSomething()
}).listen()
```